# How to get PID of foreground app programatically in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, linux, macos, pid

I need to get PID of foreground app programatically(in C or Obj C) in OS X.

How to solve the following problem?

Comment: What is "the following problem"?

Comment: I don't know how to get PID of the foreground application which user currently uses.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far to solve the problem? What documentation have you read on the subject so far?

Comment: Why did you tag `Linux` a `MacOSX` specific question?

Comment: Because it I mentioned that it could be poor C (*UNIX based) code using e.g. /sys/ etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
pid_t pid=NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.frontmostApplication.processIdentifier;
```

Answer (score 0):

... In a more general way, using the Terminal, entering "*top*" will display all current active processes, their PID, Uptime, CPU usage [....]...

Comment: I needed to do that programatically.